# Lubuntu - what task switchers with previews can I install?

Tags: lubuntu

I'm looking for a more contemporary task switcher for LXDE. I find the gnome one to be a perfect one. I also like tiled windows preview like what is presented in Gnome Shell Activities. I take the necessity of compositor installation into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Skippy-xd](https://code.google.com/p/skippy-xd/) offers a lightweight spread-like function.

Demonstration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVRPCd7OS38

There's no PPA and I wasn't able to find any `.debs`, so you will have to compile it manually. After installation you can add a hotkey for `skippy-xd` by modifying your Openbox configuration file:

```
leafpad ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
```

Add the following lines under the `keyboard` section:

```
<keybind key="W-s">
  <action name="Execute">
     <command>skippy-xd</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

where `W-s` corresponds with <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

First note: I am running `xcompmgr`, no idea if skippy will work on a non-compositing dsktop as well.

Second note: I have a precompiled amd64 `.deb` of skippy on my hard drive (one that I compiled myself in order to install it). I don't know what the askubuntu policy on spreading prepackaged binaries is, but if you're struggling with compiling skippy on your own I might be able to upload my version for you.

Comment: Good one! To anyone with other switchers tips - please edit MHC's answer.